# How to open URL without leaving the application

Tags: iphone

Whenever I click the button I want to open `google.com` but it closes my app; how can I launch the URL in my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try opening the url in uiwebView... It wont exit the application and will open up the URL in your application itself...

Try the below code on your click

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"];    
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];    
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very useful class called CustomWebView that could solve your problem: http://www.silviodaminato.it/wordpress/solutions/surfing-the-web-in-app

Answer (score 1):

Create a UIWebView in your Interface Builder and connect it through an IBOutlet to your ViewController, when your are about to load the webpage

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"];
 NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithU RL:url];
 [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];

Answer (score 0):

When you open an URL, MobileSafari will be launched. Unless your application is multi-task-handled, your application will quit when the URL is launched. Consider handling multi-tasking feature in iOS4. Read Apple documentation for more information.